# Set conditional formatting to compare content to cells in different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Looking for a way to do conditional formatting on two Excel sheets. The spreadsheet is a log of public patrons with lastname, firstname, date, time, staffinitials, CPU number. I need a way to compare the last name of all entries to a second sheet containing names. Then highlight if they match. Any Ideas?

Comment: Offering a possible solution will depend greatly on what version of Excel you are using. Excel 2010 started allowing references to other worksheets in the same workbook. Prior to that, a named range could be used to fool conditional formatting into using cell references on other worksheets.

Comment: Using 2010. Are there any guides online that show examples or working books I could use to look at how they did it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `COUNTIF()` or `MATCH()` function should take care of this handily. Let's say that you want to highlight any last names in *Sheet1* column A where that are found in *Sheet2* column B.

First select Sheet1's column A with A1 as the `ActiveCell`. Next choose Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. When the *New Formatting Rule* dialog opens, choose the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* option and supply `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B, $A1)` for the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box. Click `Format` and choose a red `Fill`. Click OK to accept the formatting and then OK again to create the new rule.

The last names in Sheet1's column A that have matches in Sheet2's column B will be highlighted in red.

*Alternate CF Rule formula:* `=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1, Sheet2!$B:$B, 0))`

[Conditional Formatting -- Introduction](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html) (Contextures.com)

Comment: GREAT! Thanks I ended up using the COUNTIF(). My problem was I was trying the alt rule and did not have it set up properly.